# Select all probes at main

Tags: starcraft-2

Looking at replays, keeping the player camera mode, I see some players select all probes they have at their main while having their view elsewhere.

How can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: Was watching an sc2replay file (loaded the actual file in SC). It was Huk vs Ret (http://www.sc2rep.com/replays/show/id/2707)

Comment: The person I had my view on was Huk, and I was watching it at Normal speed.

Comment: I watched it through and I never saw what you described.  Can you give me a timestamp?

Comment: I haven't watched the replay, but I do watch pros play at tournaments and it's not unusual to see them select all workers at a specific base by simply boxing over the entire mineral line. They are presumably doing this in order to count how many workers they have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possibility in my mind is command groups. At a previous time, he selected a batch of probes, held <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and pressed a number, <kbd>1</kbd> - <kbd>0</kbd> (number row only, not keypad). When looking elsewhere, all you have to do is press the assigned number in order to recall that selection.

Holding shift+# adds the currently selected units to the selected command group.
Holding ctrl+# creates the currently selected units in the selected command group.

shift = additive
ctrl = replace

Comment: I thought of this too, but strangely enough in the replay he doesn't have all his workers in a work group.

Comment: I was going to include "idle workers via F1" in my answer, but I remembered that that only works one worker at a time. If it's anything else, I don't know what else it could be. And on the flip side: Replays show command groups? Weird.

Comment: @VxJasonxV Ctrl-F1 selects all idle workers, but that isn't likely to be it anyway.

Comment: Really? Nice! Never knew that before.

Comment: I believe Shift-F1 will also add one idle worker to your selection, fwiw.

Comment: I think that viewing the replay in Normal mode didn't show me how the camera jumped back and forth from the nexus back to the action point. I think in the end, they actually do jump back to the nexus to select the workers. Seems they do it really quick.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't watched the replay, but I do watch pros play at tournaments and it's not unusual to see them select all workers at a specific base by simply boxing over the entire mineral line. They are presumably doing this in order to count how many workers they have.

If a player doesn't have a standard control group set up and their workers aren't idle, I believe what you describe is impossible. Are you sure you were still in first person view?

Comment: Ok thank you guys, that must of been what happened, only they did it really quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to select workers at the start!